# Website activity feed shows default facebook thumbnails in stead of og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails, meta-tags

As the title suggests I am having trouble getting the correct thumbnails in my websites activity feed. When a user likes an article the activity feed works fine and shows the article liked. However it always shows the default facebook thumbnail image.

[image]

I have used the facebook debugger and it does not show any errors or warnings and it *does* show the correct og:image.

---

## What have I tried

I have tried liking the pages I pulled through the FB debugger to see if a hard refresh would perhaps solve the problem, it did not.
I have tried specifying the articles with article type og:article, in hope i would solve the problem, this did not work either.
I have read through the facebook documentation and I find it very lacking when you are looking for something that does not go as planned, I did not find anything related to the activity feed thumbnails in here.

I think the problem might lay in facebook their image cache, but I'm not entirely sure. I read that there really isn't a way to hard refresh that + I would have to do it for every page/article on the website which is not logical.

Hopefully some of you have had the same problems and can point me in the right direction. Cheers

**edit**
Here are my meta tags (along with smarty template enginge)

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}{$smarty.server.REDIRECT_URL}">
<meta property="og:title" content="{$facebook_like_title|default:'*website name*'}">
{if $facebook_like_description|trim != ":"}
<meta property="og:description" content="{$facebook_like_description|default:'*Default like description*'}">
{else}
<meta property="og:description" content="*Default like description*">
{/if}
<meta property="og:image" content="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}/img/logo.png">
{if $article}
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="article:author" content="123456789"> 
<meta property="article:author" content="123456789">
{else}
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
{/if}
<meta property="og:site_name" content="website.com" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="****************" />
```

FB activity feed:

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; overflow: hidden; width: 220px; height: 300px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="fb-activity" data-site="website.com" data-app-id="*******************" data-width="220" data-height="300" data-header="true" data-border-color="#2F5480" data-font="arial" data-recommendations="false"></div>
</div>
```

Like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}/{$news->readonUrl}" data-send="false" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

**Edit 2**
Here is a screenshot from the activity feed:
[image]
I have removed the first users profile picture (privacy and all that) but it is showing up correctly. The second user has got a default profile picture.

Now what I want is those "filler stories" to have the correct thumbnail (which is specified as the og:image) and not the default one.

Here is an example link which FB should be scraping when liked (first filler story in this case):
http://sportflock.com/food/voedingsschemas
FB lint:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsportflock.com%2Ffood%2Fvoedingsschemas

Comment: It would help if you could post the code/XFBML of your activity feed and like button (or 'like' action type) and your og:xx meta tags for the article.  Are you sure the default FB thumbnail is not the default user thumbnail? (the thumbnail used for users that have no profile image)

Comment: @DonnLee I've added the code + I'm 100% sure that it's not the default user thumbnail.

Comment: When the og object is liked, there's a primary actor and in every case that I can remember, the thumbnail displayed in the activity feed is the thumbnail of that actor (the *user*), not og:image.  Are you saying the user's profile pic is not being displayed in the activity feed?  Just want to make sure your user has a real, human photo.

Comment: @DonnLee no, user profile pics are being displayed by the activity feed. Have a look at the standard facebook example (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/); it shows a picture of the "page/article" liked/recommended. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem eventually solved itself. It must have been the facebook cache or something. After not having checked on this problem for several months, I came to check on it to see if anything had changed. Suddenly all thumbnails showed correctly without any help from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a screenshot of the activity feed you see. But, I think what you see in the example are filler stories when the activity feed doesn't have enough real stories from real users to show.

This screenshot has 3 filler stories:

[image: activity feed with filler stories]

Note, that the activity feed in the example (in the FB docs) will look different for each viewer.  For example, when there is lots of activity (or when the viewer has lots of friends who have actions on the site), there will be a real person next to every story in the activity feed.

At this point, I think this is what's needed:  Screenshot of the activity feed exhibiting the issue, and link/url in the story that is scraped by FB.

Comment: Yes, that does seem strange.  I will look at this when I get some free time later today.

Comment: It seems to display one of your pages with the correct og:image in this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5lwqL.png
 ... 

I created a test activity feed on my website, and it showed all og:image's correctly. I used the like button to generate test activities/stories. I was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hey thanks, I never got one with an image showing correctly I can now have a look at what's different with that page at least.